# Espeak reads separate letters instead of words

Tags: android, locale, text-to-speech, persian, espeak

At the first time, I tried to use the Google's default TTS engine in the following code, but I found that, the Persian language is not supported!

So, I downloaded and installed `espeak RedZoc TTS engine` on my phone and changed the default TTS language to Persian. And when I checked it in my phone settings or inside RedZoc app, it works well.

But when I run my code inside my phone, it reads the letters separately instead of reading the complete word! (for example it should say `SALAM` but it says `Arabic Sin Lam Alef Mim` )

MainActivity:

```
package com.m.ttsapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    String text;
    EditText et;
    TextToSpeech tts;
    Button btn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et=findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button1);

        tts=new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {


            @Override
            public void onInit(int status)
            {
                if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
                {
                    int result=tts.setLanguage(Locale.);
                    if(result==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result==TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED)
                    {
                        Log.e("error", "This Language is not supported");
                    }
                    else{
                        ConvertTextToSpeech();
                    }
                }
                else
                    Log.e("error", "Initilization Failed!");
            }
        });

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ConvertTextToSpeech();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {

        if(tts != null)
        {

            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }


    private void ConvertTextToSpeech()
    {
        text = et.getText().toString();
        if(text == null || "".equals(text))
        {
            text = "Content not available";
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }else
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }


}
```

I know maybe I must change this line of the code but don't know changing it to what? `int result=tts.setLanguage(Locale.);`

Or maybe I must forget all of this code and write another one? But how?

Comment: The engine probably assumes SALAM is an acronym. Try it in lower case.

Comment: @brandall: In fact I try `سلام` and I wrote the example in English to clrafy what I mean

Comment: Could that not still be interpreted as an acronym by the Engine?

Comment: @brandall: I don't know! When I try `سلام` outside of my app(inside the phone TTS settings or RedZoc app), it works fine, but inside of my app it says the letters!

I think maybe I must change something inside my code?

Comment: Maybe it is something about unicode problem?(Although I don't know really what problem)

Comment: Log the output of `et.getText().toString()` to double check what you are requesting the engine speaks.

Comment: `02-24 10:55:23.959 30824-30824/com.m.ttsapp E/tag: text is  سلام`

Comment: The problem is here: `result=tts.setLanguage(Locale.);` because the Persian isn't a value of `Locale`

Comment: Try `tts.setLanguage(new Locale("fa","IR"))`;

Comment: You are great! It worked!
Post is as an answer!

Comment: Great. I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'inbuilt' `Locale.PERSIAN` and therefore you need to create the Locale.

```
final Locale persianLocale = new Locale("fa","IR");
```

And then set it:

```
tts.setLanguage(persianLocale);
```